# Шаблонизатор, не перестраивающий DOM при обновлении

Tags: javascript, dom, веб-программирование, шаблонизаторы

Шаблонизаторов сейчас ну очень много и я уже заблудился в Google, перебирая тысячи их. Хочу найти такой, который будет уметь не только из строки делать строку, но который умеет находить и выполнять только изменения в DOM. Причем без использования observables, т.е. Knockout.js предлагать не нужно — я не хочу возиться с `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` на каждый шаг, я просто скажу руками когда что-то надо обновить. Правда, в идеале, я не всегда знаю что (пришли новые данные, и вручную смотреть разницу со старой версией не очень-то и хочется).

Я хочу отрисовать начальное:

```
t = "( Строка с кодом шаблона )";
data = {
    fields: {foo: "Foo", bar: "Bar"},
    notice: null
};
$("#target").empty().render_template(t, data);
```

И потом мог обновлять данные, не перерисовывая весь DOM (т.е. сохраняя состояние элементов):

```
data.fields["foo"] = "Foo!";
data.notice = { message: "Here, I've added an exclamation mark for you." };
$("#target").render_template(null /* шаблон оставить старым */, data);
```

Тут от шаблонизатора требуется понимание что такое DOM, и умение запоминать какие переменные пошли в какие атрибуты и текстовые ноды, *с учетом семантики элементов*. Т.е., по некоему

```
{{ foreach fields as name: field }}
   <p><textarea name="input_{{ name }}">{{ field.value }}</textarea></p>
{{ /foreach }}
{{ if notice }}<p class="notice">{{ notice.message }}</p>{{ /if }}
```

шаблонизатор должен «осознавать» что `<textarea name="foo">Foo</textarea>` будет брать данные из объекта `data.fields.foo` и понимать, что атрибут `name` строился как `"input_" + data.fields["foo"].name`, а содержимое — это `data.fields["foo"].value`. Причем — повторюсь — с учетом семантики — раз это `<textarea>`, то, семантически, текстовая нода имеет отношение к DOM-атрибуту `value`.

Когда поменялся элемент, то обновления должны происходить только с одним `<textarea>` (в нужных местах), а не приводить к перерисовке всего шаблона. Т.е. соседние `<textarea>` «пострадать» никак не должны.

При этом (как еще одно отличие от того же Knockout) требуется отсутствие ошибок от того, что используется `data.notice.message`, которого изначально не существует. Разумеется, при условии, что эта часть дерева заблокирована if'ом от существования.

От самих шаблонов нужно ровно две вещи:

- Простейшая логика условий существования (проверка на false, null, undefined и пустой список, опционально, но желательно — строгое сравнение с константой)
- Простейшая логика скрытия (аналогично условиям, но не создает/удаляет DOM-ноды, а скрывает или показывает их)
- Простейшая логика итерации (пробег по массиву или собственным ключам объекта)

Синтаксис никакого значения не имеет.

Работа нужна только в браузерах и только разумно современных (2009 года и позднее, никакой некромантии).

Comment: >При этом (как еще одно отличие от того же Knockout) требуется отсутствие ошибок от того, что используется data.notice.message, которого изначально не существует. 

[каких ошибок](http://jsfiddle.net/mLe4N/)?

по делу, вам нужно нечто вроди [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/)

Comment: А, ну значит я не осилил просто, я делал `data-bind="text: notice.message"`, что приводило к характерному отказу работать.

Ember — это вариант, но он живет на observables. А я, все же, пожалуй, хочу слабо связанные компоненты, чтобы те же модели в любой момент времени можно было начисто заменить.

Comment: ещё недавно прочитал про [Dirty checking](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165275/), который используется в AngularJS, но никогда с ним не работал.

Comment: @drdaeman: верным помечен устаревший ответ, исправьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы буквально описали поведение фронтенд-движков, основанных на концепции Virtual DOM.

К ним относятся, например: широко распиареный в настоящее время [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), менее известный, не менее функциональный, зато более быстрый и лёгкий [Mithril](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/), а также концептуально выверенный и расширяемый [virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/branches).

Причиной появления таких движков является то, что все операции с реальным DOM происходят относительно медленно и в высокодинамичных приложениях являются самым узким местом.

Принцип действия этих библиотек основан на создании легковесной эмуляции DOM и diff-алгоритме, применяющем в реальный документ только изменённые части виртуального дерева.

Помимо бенефитов в плане производительности, такие движки могут улучшить качество вашего фронтенд-кода, т.к. позволяют реализовать полностью функциональный стиль манипуляций с элементами, используя при этом весь арсенал средств Javascript - нативные forEach, map, reduce и так далее.

**Дополнительные материалы**:

Статья о том, как организован Virtual DOM в React: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/diff/

Простая и понятная имплементация diff-алгоритма: https://gist.github.com/Raynos/8414846

PS: также, вполне адекватным ответом на этот вопрос, несмотря на неприятие автором knockoutjs, является Angular и его аналоги - тот-же Knockout, Vue, Ractive, а особенно последний, ввиду его простоты и нетребовательности к уже используемой архитектуре.

Answer (score 0):

Шаблонизатора такого не знаю, но связка из любого шаблонизатора + [Metamorph.js](https://github.com/tomhuda/metamorph.js/) может оказаться вполне годна для частичного изменения на странице.

А что до скрытия\показа - вручную по стилям, сомневаюсь что есть такие шаблонизаторы.